# Magento customer login hangs on some accounts

Tags: database, customer-account, magento2.4.2, apache, customer-login

I have a magento 2.4.2 install, and some customers can't login into their account area, the website just hangs. They don't get no error or anything. It was that bad that it brought down a whole server when multiple customers were logging in at the same time.

after changing the server, I'm facing this issue then I restarted the apache and site is working.

Comment: Have youtry to compile the website one's? And website running on the production mode?

Comment: @kiran do you see any errors at webserver level or in the magento var/log?

Comment: No, I didn’t see any error. Customer will keep on loading.

Comment: @DianaBotean - AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/b/public_html/app/etc/config.php